# In jQuery, how do you remove all the divs pertaining to a certain class INSIDE a certain div class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

If I have a div that contains other divs, how do I make it so I remove all the divs inside the original div?  That might have been confusing, heres a code example:

```
<div class="test"><div class="delete"></div></div>
<div class="delete"></div>
```

How do I remove the 'delete' div thats INSIDE the 'test' div ONLY and still keep the one outside.  Thanks!!

Comment: You don't even need the jQuery UI plugin or any other plugins for this, just to let you know. Just follow what Boycs and everyone else said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div.test').find('div.delete').remove();
```

should do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

actually a combination of both:

```
$('div.test div.delete').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete any div inside

```
$('div.test div').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure there won't be any other children elements that has a `.delete` class, you can get away with this:

```
$('div.test > .delete').remove();
```